# printf network data

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp

I wrote the following function and works fine:

```
int NetworkSocket::readDatagrams(unsigned char *buffer, string &srcAddress, unsigned short int & srcPort,size_t frameSize)
{

    unsigned int maximumPacketSize = sizeof(buffer);//frameSize ;
    int returnValue ;
    sockaddr_in from;
    socklen_t fromLength = sizeof( from );
    int receivedBytes;

    fromLength = sizeof(this->getSocketAddressStructureOfServer());
    receivedBytes = recvfrom( this->socketFD, buffer, maximumPacketSize, 0, (sockaddr *)&this->getSocketAddressStructureOfServer(), &fromLength     ) ;

    cout << receivedBytes << endl;
    returnValue = receivedBytes;
    if ( receivedBytes <= 0 )
        returnValue = -1;

    /// exporting data
    //
    srcAddress = inet_ntoa(this->getSocketAddressStructureOfServer().sin_addr);
    srcPort = ntohs( ( unsigned short int)this->getSocketAddressStructureOfServer().sin_port );


    return returnValue;
}
```

When i apply it,  it return in ref srcAddress and port Even buffer is full, but i can't printf buffer, how i do it? wireshakr show 000010001 it means 5 bytes, and i need to examine it and compare to my data.

Comment: Note that `unsigned int maximumPacketSize = sizeof(buffer);` sets the maximum packet size to the size of a `char*`, which typically is 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: Also, I fail to see the exact line, where the printf fails...or any printf, for that matter.

Comment: `::` is a syntax error in C. Could it be C++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int maximumPacketSize = sizeof(buffer);//frameSize ;
```

This line is faulty, since you're requesting the size of the pointer variable (which always equals '4' on a 32-bit system). You have to pass the maximum buffer size manually, or simply 'know' it, which shouldn't be a problem, since you instantiated it in the first place.

In the essence that means, you can never get more than 4 bytes.

Comment: Now , Do you have any idea for examining them?

Comment: Examine what exactly? The content of the buffer? Are you transmitting a number? A string? If it's a number, try using printf("%d", *((int *)buffer));, which will temporarily cast the buffer to an 'int * Array' and return the first element. If you're transferring a string, use printf("%s", Buffer);, but make sure, that the string is terminated by '0'.